# WPF bind Combobox.ItemsSource inside a TabControl.ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I have this XAML:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I'd like to Bind `Items` that is a custom `TabItem` class, in particular:

```
public class CustomItem : TabItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Foo { get; set; }
}
```

in MainWindow.cs I have defined `Items`:

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomItem> Items {get; set;} = new ObservableCollection<CustomItem>{new CustomItem{Foo = new ObservableCollection<string>{"foo1", "foo2"}  } };
```

I'd like to populate the combobox defined above with the Foo elements, so I'd like to see "foo1" and "foo2".
Actually I could not see anything: I think it is a `DataContext` problem, so I try with the following code but nothing happens:

```
<ComboBox d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:CustomItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}/>"
```

How could I fix my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XAML is pretty much fine, but you shouldn't be deriving `CustomItem` from `TabItem`. That's causing the `TabControl` to treat it very differently, and there's no need for that.

Instead, you should derive it from a viewmodel base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and its properties should raise `PropertyChanged` when they change their values. You can easily find many examples of how to do that right here on Stack Overflow. But for now, here are some quick changes to your code that'll get you moving:

```
public class CustomItem
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Foo { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public String SelectedFoo { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFoo}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```